# Fourier transformation of an infinitely continuous differentiable function with compact support

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f$ be a function in $L^1(R^n)$ and also in $C_c^\infty$ (with compact support). Does this mean the Fourier transformation of $f$ is also in $L^1$?

Comment: Yes, it is. You should use that the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is a Schwartz function.

Comment: @Sqrt I haven't learned about Schwartz function yet, but I think we can prove the statement by using partial integrations (we get extra $1/\xi_k$ term every time we integrate, so we should be able to estimate the integral of $|f|$ and make sure its finite. Do you think this would work?

Comment: Yes, this would work